# Building Telegram TDLib for C# Windows (.NET Core) - Telegram.Td library missing

Tags: c#, .net, cmake, telegram, tdlib

Noob question incoming. I'm trying to create custom Telegram client using C#.
I'm following the instructions from [tdlib](https://tdlib.github.io/td/build.html?language=C%23)

Config is:
Language: C#
OS: Windows (.NET Core)
Shell application: PowerShell
Bitness: 64

Which gives me the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/tdlib/td.git
cd td
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg.git
cd vcpkg
git checkout 1b1ae50e1a69f7c659bd7d731e80b358d21c86ad
./bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
./vcpkg.exe install gperf:x64-windows openssl:x64-windows zlib:x64-windows
cd ..
Remove-Item build -Force -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -A x64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=../tdlib -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE:FILEPATH=../vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake ..
cmake --build . --target install --config Release
cd ..
cd ..
dir td/tdlib
```

After PowerShell finishes his job (no errors), I'm opening \td\example\csharp example, and `using Td = Telegram.Td` lib is missing.

I was unable to find this lib anywhere in "td" directory.

I Googled any complete up-to-date step by step tutorials (that show how to build the lib and run working example) where I could see what have I missed or did wrong, but found none.

Can someone please help me to find out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: does doing `cmake --build . --target install` actually make it build first before installing? I've never done things that way.